# Better ways to collect all unused field of an Object in aeson's Parser?

Tags: haskell, aeson

Suppose I want to implement `FromJSON` for a data type. Below are the complete source code:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE
    NamedFieldPuns
  , OverloadedStrings
  , TupleSections
  , ViewPatterns
  #-}
module Main
  ( main
  ) where

import Data.Aeson
import Control.Monad

import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HM
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M
import qualified Data.Text as T

data Foo
  = Foo
  { aaa :: Int
  , bbb :: T.Text
  , ccc :: Maybe (Int, Int)
  , extra :: M.Map T.Text T.Text
  }

instance FromJSON Foo where
  parseJSON = withObject "Foo" $ \obj -> do
    aaa <- obj .: "aaa"
    bbb <- obj .: "bbb"
    ccc <- obj .:? "ccc"
    let existingFields = T.words "aaa bbb ccc"
        obj' =
          -- for sake of simplicity, I'm not using the most efficient approach.
          filter ((`notElem` existingFields) . fst)
          . HM.toList
          $ obj
    (M.fromList -> extra) <- forM obj' $ \(k,v) ->
      withText "ExtraText" (pure . (k,)) v
    pure Foo {aaa,bbb,ccc,extra}

main :: IO ()
main = pure ()
```

This data type `Foo` has a bunch of fields of potentially different types and in the end there is `extra` to collect all remaining fields.

Obviously no one would enjoy updating `existingFields` every time some fields get add/remove/update-ed, any recommended approach on collecting unused fields?

An alternative that I can think of is to stack a `StateT` on top with `obj` (converted to `Map`) as the initial state, and use something like `Data.Map.splitLookup` to "discharge" used fields. But I'm reluctant to do so as it will involve some lifting around monad stacks and it doesn't sound very good performance-wise removing elements one at a time from `Map` in comparison to filtering through `HashMap` in one pass in the end.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your use case: Do you assume that the structure of the JSON data you unmarshall changes while your application is not updated? in the sense that fields are added? If yes, what do you want your application to do with these extra fields it discovers?

Comment: @UlrichSchuster Yes. The JSON data (which is downloaded from a server) could have structural changes when my application is not updated. Not all fields are relevant to my application but I want this datatype to be lossless, as the same data needs to be reconstructured as a local file. You just gave me some new idea here: if my application is read-only  (this is actually true!) I can just keep the original bytestring around when it comes to writing the file and don't bother with this "lossless" idea.

Comment: Another option then is to store Aeson's internal representation. Aeson parses files in two septs: First, it converts the raw byte strings into JSONValue objects, and then tries to map these values to your custom types. You could access and store the JSON Values for later use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> no one would enjoy updating existingFields every time some fields get
>   add/remove/update-ed

Consider this function

```
import Data.Aeson.Types (Parser)
import Data.Text (Text)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer
import Data.Functor.Compose

keepName :: (Object -> Text -> Parser x) 
         ->  Object -> Text -> Compose (Writer [Text]) Parser x
keepName f obj fieldName = Compose $ do
    tell [fieldName]
    pure (f obj fieldName)
```

It takes as input an operator like [`.:`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.7.1/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#v:.:) or [`.:?`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.7.1/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#v:.:-63-) and "enriches" its result value so that, instead of returning a [`Parser`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.7.1/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#t:Parser), it returns a [`Parser`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.7.1/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#t:Parser) nested inside a [`Writer`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Strict.html#t:Writer) that serves to accumulate the supplied field names. The composition is wrapped in the [`Compose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html#t:Compose) newtype, which automatically gives us an `Applicative` instance because, as mentioned in the docs:

> (Applicative f, Applicative g) => Applicative (Compose f g)

(The composition is not a `Monad` though. Also take note that we are using `Writer` and not `WriterT`. We are [nesting `Applicative`s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZ9FpG8May8&feature=youtu.be&t=370), not applying monad transformers).

The rest of the code doesn't change that much:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ApplicativeDo #-}

instance FromJSON Foo where
  parseJSON = withObject "Foo" $ \obj -> do
    let Compose (runWriter -> (parser,existingFields)) = 
            do aaa <- keepName (.:) obj "aaa"
               bbb <- keepName (.:) obj "bbb"
               ccc <- keepName (.:?) obj "ccc"
               pure Foo {aaa,bbb,ccc,extra = mempty}            
        obj' =
            filter ((`notElem` existingFields) . fst)
            . HM.toList
            $ obj
    (M.fromList -> extra) <- forM obj' $ \(k,v) ->
      withText "ExtraText" (pure . (k,)) v
    r <- parser
    pure $ r { extra }
```

Comment: For years I know Applicative is composable but I've never thought about any use case of that. This answer is a nice one, also thanks for that video, quite interesting to watch.